# How to change input box autofocus cursor size and width in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to change input field auto focus cursor's height and width.

**app.component.html**

```
<input class="subdisplay" [ngModel]="input | number" type="text" 
      (keyup)="getValue(box.value)" name="name" autofocus #box/>
```

I want to change cursor width and height in input box in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the caret. You cant change the width of the caret but can change properties like,

```
input {
 caret-color:
 caret-shape: // This is experimental
}
```

PS This has nothing to do with Angular